# urllib2 catches 404 error while URL exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, http-status-code-404, urllib2

I faced with strange bug: urllib2 catches 404 error, while openning a valid url. I tryed it in browser, the url can be opened. Also I pass user-agent.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
uri = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8Sii8G5CNvY/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=OIIIAPOKNtx1OiZbAqdORlzl92g'
try:
  req = urllib2.Request(uri, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
  file = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
  if err.code == 404:
    return "Not Found"
```

Why I get this error? Thank you for answers.

Comment: Well, if you test the uri on some advanced HTTP client or open the development console of your web browser, it throws you a 404 error. Seems to work fine.

Comment: The server you are trying to access acts weirdly: it responds with 404 followed by the actual file. Command line tool `wget` fails to get the document, too, but `curl` gets it. There is nothing wrong with your code, apparently `urllib2` was not designed to handle situations like this.

Comment: But how I can download it if it was 404 error? Can I just do data = file.read(1024)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the body anyway, simply read the error response with an `err.read()`:

```
import urllib2
uri = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8Sii8G5CNvY/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=OIIIAPOKNtx1OiZbAqdORlzl92g'
try:
  req = urllib2.Request(uri, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
  file = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
  if err.code == 404:
    print "Not Found"
    print err.read()
```