# python3 urlopen raises 404 error while openning in the browser

Tags: python, urllib

I'm using `urllib.request` with python 3.4.6 to open `https://www.ethz.ch/` (The actual url is longer but the problem is the same), which opens fine with Firefox but throws a 404 error with python.

Here is the code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
connection = urlopen('https://www.ethz.ch/')
```

and it gives the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./generate_group_meetings_ical.py", line 9, in <module>
    connection = urlopen('https://www.ethz.ch/')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 470, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 580, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 508, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 588, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not found UA
```

The code used to work fine though. Another piece of information is that I'm not root on the machine and python3 was upgraded from 3.4.5 to 3.4.6. So the comes either from the web server side or from the python side. I'm not a python nor a web expert so I couldn't figure it out myself.

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Sounds like a user agent problem, try setting the user agent string to something else to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Francisco, it solved the problem. I posted an answer describing it.

Comment: Just had the same problem while building a scraper for exercise sheets at the same university lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Francisco's comment and [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943023/8257951) I could make it work with the following code

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('https://www.ethz.ch/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
connection = urlopen(req)
```

I also checked the original version with python 2.7.13 and urllib2 and it worked. Apparently python 3.5 works (answer from Laxmikant) and it was originally working under 3.4.5. So something happened in the upgrade from 3.4.5 to 3.4.6 that caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

@Pheidippides Check for typos if any in your entire url, it worked for me:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
$>from urllib.request import urlopen
$>connection = urlopen('https://www.ethz.ch/')
$>connection.read()
```

Comment: Thanks @Laxmikant, I ran exactly the commands you entered but at least I now know that it works with python 3.5