# HTTPError: Not Found using user-agent

Tags: python, http, urllib

I am tyring to open an url like following:

```
import urllib.request

url = "https://www.chess.cornell.edu/index.php/users/calculato%20rs/calculator-absolute-flux-measurement-using-xpd100"
# I tried to access to this url.
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
# using the user agent like many answers suggested.
f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

However, I always got the error like following:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Not Found
```

Thanks a lot for any helps!

Comment: The URL returns 404 Not Found for me, I'm not sure what's the question about

Comment: Thanks a lot! Same to me but the page actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

I used the requests library and it worked fine

```
import request
r = requests.get("https://www.chess.cornell.edu/index.php/users/calculato%20rs/calculator-absolute-flux-measurement-using-xpd100")
```

even though it returns a,

```
<Response [404]>
```

you can still use `r.text` to get the html of the site

this probably happens because the site returns a status `404` (Not found) even though it actually returns a valid page. While `urllib` panics and throws an error your browser and `requests` will still follow through and show us the page.

Glad if this helps `:)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the `requests` the got the `text` from the html. However, I was trying to write up a script to post some value to the website and got the calculated results later.If I continue using this `text` HTML, can I do such interaction with the website at all? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: By the way, I was trying to use `urllib.request.urlopen()` for my application. Based on this situation, is there anything I could try not using `urllib.request.urlopen()`, thanks

Comment: @ypjia you could use `requests.post` to do post requests. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fetch response body even for 404 error, this is [how it's done using `urllib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40943023/9288580):

```py
try:
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    f = err
```

This is a very simplistic snippet, of course, assuming you want to do `f.read()` later on to process the content.  In a robust program there should be all kinds of checks for HTTP response code, content types and so on.

---

There is nothing wrong with using `requests` (as suggested by @DeeraWijesundara), of course.  In fact, I would personally use `requests` too in a similar case, but for completeness' sake I've decided to add an stdlib-only answer.